# jQuery.append() ignores element in htmlstring

Tags: jquery

Just curious if anyone has insight into this jQuery behavior, which seems buggy to me.

I have an empty select form element that I want to append options to, one of which is hidden by wrapping it in a span element with display style set to none.

snippet 1 - appends the options but ignores the span element:

```
var myOptions = '<option value="1">1</option><span style="display:none;"><option value="2">2</option></span>';
$('#mySelect').append(myOptions);
```

snippet 2 - works as intended:

```
var myOptions = '<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>';
$('#mySelect').append(myOptions);
$('#mySelect').find('options:eq(1)').wrap('<span style="display:none;"/>');
```

Comment: probably because it's invalid HTML. Why not set `display:none` directly to option?

Comment: styling the option to display:none doesn't hide it in IE ... that's exactly what I was doing until it was tested in IE

Comment: An option could be to remove it and append it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only valid child elements for `<select>` is `<option>` and `<optgroup>` (courtesy of Marcell)

Comment: Thank you.  I was thoroughly confused.

Answer (score 0):

Don't append the option you want to hide, instead store it on the select.

```
var myOptions = $.parseHTML('<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option>');
$('#mySelect').append(myOptions.eq(0)).data("hiddenOptions",myOptions.eq(1));
```

Now if you wanted to add it back, it's conveniently stored on the select's data object.

```
$("#mySelect").data("hiddenOptions").appendTo("#mySelect")
```